# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: Archiver error. Connect AS SYSDBA only until resolved

Tags: java, oracle

I am getting below error while connecting to oracle database.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: Archiver error. Connect AS SYSDBA only until resolved.07-09-2016 12:25:44 ERROR DBUtils:122 - loginUser Exception :java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: Archiver error. Connect AS SYSDBA only until resolved.

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:444)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:407)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:416)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.sne.dao.DBUtils.loginUser(DBUtils.java:55)
at com.sne.servlets.SELogin.doPost(SELogin.java:46)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Error While Connecting db through SQL Developer...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The archiver is responsible for taking the online redo logs and writing them off to a safe place in the event they are needed for a database recovery.

Currently they are unable to do this, so they are preventing any operation on the database until the DBA goes in to sort it all out.

Answer (score 9):

You have to free up space by deleting archivelogs & backups.

1. Use the rman(Recovery Manager) command. Just type rman on the command line
2. Connect to the target database
   [image: Rman command and Connect to the target DB]
3. Delete backups using

   `delete backup;`
   or only the obsolete backup files with:

   `delete obsolete;`
4. Remove archive logs:

   `delete force copy of archivelog all;`

**Ref**: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=153283327861734&id=2340995.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=mku6itxsh_4

Comment: if i run the above comment will it somehow affect the running of my application 
like will it go down or somthing

Answer (score 0):

Since the Oracle archive is full. Create a maintenance job to perform a daily cleanup.